# Does OpenOffice 3.3.0 still have the command "oowriter"?

Tags: openoffice.org

My Ubuntu is 10.10 with some default version of OpenOffice. In order to install some plugin, I have uninstalled the Openoffice and installed a new version 3.3.0 by downloading it from its official website, following [this instruction](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Installing_on_Debian_based_Distros).

But in the new OpenOffice, I find that a command I used quite often before called `oowriter` does not exist anymore. I wonder if `3.3.0` has an equivalent command? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an idea if it has the same command anymore, but if it's in the Applications Menu, then you could go to *System->Preferences->Main Menu*. There select the application you want to know the name of and click Properties. The command to execute that application shows up there.

This is a screenshot where I found the command to execute LibreOffice. The procedure  is very similar to finding OpenOffice Writer's command, if you were wondering why the screenshot if it's not OpenOffice Writer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have installed OOo to a directory where the system does not normally search for executables. The executables for OOo are now in `/opt/openoffice.org3/program` or `/opt/openoffice.org3/bin` something similar, and you will need to either:

- add that directory to your $PATH,
- create launcher scripts,
- create symlinks into `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`,
- or you will need to type the full path each time.

You could also install LibreOffice (recommended) from the PPA.

Add

```
ppa:libreoffice/ppa
```

to your sources and then install the "libreoffice" package.

Comment: Thanks! I found `/opt/openoffice.org3/program/resource`, but there is only one file called `oooen-US.res`.
`

Comment: How is libreoffice recommended over openoffice? Does libreoffice have more features than openoffice? I am interested in if its calc has nonlinear optimization algorithms.

Comment: @Tim LibreOffice is recommended because it is the successor of OpenOffice, which is essentially dead, and if you ever upgrade your Ubuntu install, that is what you will be getting. I'm not sure if it's Calc supports that feature, but it possibly does.